# Bind select with array of objects and display details when item is selected from select tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array

```
$scope.items= [
{ name: "Name1", email: "email1", password: "pas1" },
{ name: "Name2", email: "email2", password: "pas2" }
];
```

I want to display email value in a select tag. I am using following code but its not working. I want first item as 'Select' :

```
<select id="idItem">
<option value="-1" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option ng-repeat="o.email as o.email for o in items" value="{{o.email}}"> {{o.email}}
</option>
</select>
```

Also user can select multiple items. When user selects multiple emails from select box, message box should popup displaying Name and password of selected users.

Comment: `o.email for o in items` this could be your ng-repeat. And you don't need to add extra option tag for showing select, you can use a placeholder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select id="idItem" >
<option value="-1" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.email}}"> {{item.email}}
</option>
</select>
```

I think this would work....if it doesn't plz provide your plunkr url next time

Comment: How should I display the details when I select any values from list box? note that user can select multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use ng-options if you already have a json object containing all items. Further you need to use multiple="true" for multi-select and a ng-model to store the selected results

```
<select id="idItem" multiple="true" ng-model="selectedItems"
        ng-options="item.email for item in items">
</select>
```

Then you can create a messageBox which displays the selectedItems if you want